# How to read/write a file from a relative path in C#, WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf

It only works if I use the absolute path, but I want it relative. I tried `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory` but it goes to the **bin folder** where the files are not, they are in the **project folder**.

What should I do?

```
try
{
   using StreamReader reader = new("input.txt");
   using StreamWriter writer = new("resources\\output.txt");
   string line;

   while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
   {
      writer.WriteLine(line);
   }
      reader.Close();
      writer.Close();
}
catch (FileNotFoundException)
{
   MessageBox.Show("File Not Found");
}
```

Comment: Would addiing the files to your solution, and for each of the in their properties ask for them to be copied to the output directory (either always or if newer) work for you ? Because usually you only deploy what was in the bin/Debug folder, not what was above that.

Comment: I would suggest trying `Path.GetFullPath(...)` so you can see what your relative path actually resolves to.

Comment: All files I want to read or write must be in the **bin folder**?

Comment: Yes, the running app doesn't know about any project folder. See my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> They are in the project folder.

Well, you need to understand that there is no such thing as "project folder" at runtime.

You may for example develop your application on a machine with Visual Studio installed and keep the source code files in some directory. You then build the app and deploy the compiled binaries to a another machine which has no source code files or build tools.

You should copy the files that you are trying to read from and write to to the output directory of your executable for your relative paths to work.

Select the files in the Solution Explorer in Visual Studio and set their `Build Action` to `Content`, and `Copy to Output Directory` to `Copy if newer`.

Answer (score 0):

I just found a way to read the files in your project folder, and it also works when you create an executable.

```
using StreamReader reader = new("..\\..\\..\\input.txt");
```